# Firefox add-on description localization

Tags: firefox, localization, add-on

I've created simple restartless Firefox add-on and trying to localize it. I can not localize the add-on name and description. I'm trying to do it as it is descriped here [Localizing extension descriptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/Localizing_extension_descriptions)

Below my install.rdf file and package.json

package.json

```
{
    "name": "find_in_files",
    "title": "Find in files",    
    "id":  "{7DE613B7-54D9-4899-A018-861472402B2E}",
    "description": "Search for substring in files",
    "author": "Vitaly Shulgin",
    "license": "MPL 2.0",
    "version": "1.1",
    "unpack": "true",
    "preferences": [
        {
            "name": "SearchDirectory",
            "title": "Search directory",
            "description": "You must specify it before search. Please, be patient - it may takes some time to index documents before search will return correct result.",
            "type": "directory",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "DefaultLocale",
            "title": "Default language",
            "description": "Default language to use when searching in non-unicode documents",
            "type": "menulist",
            "value": "ru-ru",
            "options": [
                {
                    "value": "en-us",
                    "label": "English"
                },
                {
                    "value": "ru-ru",
                    "label": "Russian"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "OutputFileName",
            "title": "Temporary output file name",
            "description": "Temporary output file name",
            "type": "string",
            "value": "fif-result.html",
            "hidden": true
        }
    ]
}
```

install.rdf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>{7DE613B7-54D9-4899-A018-861472402B2E}</em:id>
    <!-- begin localizaation -->
     <em:localized>
      <Description>
        <em:locale>ru-Ru</em:locale>
        <em:name>Поиск в файлах</em:name>
        <em:description>Поиск выделенного текста в файлах</em:description>
      </Description>
    </em:localized>
    <em:localized>
      <Description>
        <em:locale>en-Us</em:locale>
        <em:name>Find in Files</em:name>
        <em:description>Search for selected text in files</em:description>         
      </Description>
    </em:localized>
    <!-- em:name>Find in files</em:name -->
    <!-- em:description>Search for selected text in files</em:description -->         
    <!-- end localizaation -->
    <em:version>1.1</em:version>
    <em:type>2</em:type>
    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
      <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id> <!--Firefox-->
      <em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
      <em:maxVersion>3.0.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>
    <em:unpack>true</em:unpack>  
    <em:creator>Vitaly A. Shulgin</em:creator>
    <em:targetPlatform>WINNT</em:targetPlatform>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - the command  "cfx xpi" from mozilla add-on sdk will overwrite install.rdf if you have it in project folder. So, to get things work properly - create xpi package, unpack it (unzip) - and you will find auto-generate install.rdf inside (!!!), substitute install.rdf with your own and re-pack xpi with zip command.

That's all, folks!